# Odd bash behavior when pasting code lines, or pressing enter

Tags: bash, shell, slurm

I have Windows 10 running the Ubuntu subsystem. I've moved to a new computer, and when I log into my university's HPC, bash behaves oddly. If I press enter multiple times, this happens:

> ```
> (base) [mylogin@login2 [cluster] ~]$                                  
> (base) [mylogin@login2 [cluster] ~]$                                  
> (base) [mylogin@login2 [cluster] ~]$ ;164R
> -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
>  
> base) [mylogin@login2 [cluster] ~]$
> ```

This is also affecting how I paste code in an interactive session: sometimes when the code chunk breaks, it creates the ";164R" string in between my code lines, breaking up the code flow, and stopping the paste mechanism.

This does not happen in my regular ubuntu bash, but only when I am logged into the cluster. (but at the same time, this didn't use to happen before I moved computers...) I can't remember having changed any configuration files...

If anyone has any ideas, please let me know :)

My HPC runs slurm 19.05.5

Comment: looks like malformed `PS1` set up in your profile

Comment: whenever it is set is for you to figure out eventually, but you can look what it is set to with `echo "$PS1"` and (for completeness) `echo "$PS2"`

Comment: echo "$PS1" results in `(base) [\u@\h\[\e[1;32m\] [rosalind]\[\e[0m\] \W]\$`
echo "$PS2" results in ` > `

Sounds like an admin problem then. I'll contact IT support

Comment: it seems something else overrides it and sets the name in the late square brackets. Note names `[cluster]` and `[rosalind]`. On the other hand, are you using some kind of multiplexer like `tmux` or `screen` or `byobu` on your terminal?

Comment: The ";164R" looks like part of a garbled escape sequence, but I don't know why it'd be being sent (let alone getting garbled). The closest I see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Terminal_input_sequences) are that if the computer asks an xterm terminal (or something emulating one) what the cursor position is, the terminal will reply with `<esc>[<rownum>;<columnnum>R`, so what you see could be the second half of a report that the cursor is in column number 164... but I'm pretty sure it isn't. It'll also send `<esc>[1;<modifiers>R` if F3 is pressed with modifier keys...

Comment: Oh, no, I manually edited my initial post to say "cluster"  instead of "rosalind". I should have been more thorough to avoid the confusion. 

I noticed that my `~/.bashrc` file has a redirection to load some parameters from `/etc/bashrc` too, which I think is a cluster-wide file, so it's probably affecting more people..

Comment: Oh.. If I do a fresh login session to the cluster, I can hold enter, and it behaves normally.. The problem starts when I use `screen` - even after I minimize the window, this bug remains happening in the original login window..

Comment: inspect your `/etc/bashrc`, `/etc/profile` and `profile.d` and your home `.profile` and `.bashrc`. I think this is the fairly complete list of scripts.

Comment: it seems misconfigured `screen` then. Those codes are what `screen` uses to communicate with it's underlying TTYs. Most likely TTY misreports its terminal capabilities, see `man termcap`.

Comment: Ok, I think I know what happened. A few weeks ago I had a problem when using `screen`: every time I would resize the window, the bash cursor would disappear, getting buried underneath what was being shown on my screen.. Then I found [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61584/how-to-solve-the-issue-that-a-terminal-screen-is-messed-up-usually-after-a-res), to include `export PROMPT_COMMAND="resize &>/dev/null ; $PROMPT_COMMAND"` in `bashrc`- I removed this line, and the problem is gone. Pheew.. I'll figure out something else for the window resizing issue, but thank you all!